# Spliting string into seperate variables in c++

Tags: c++, vector, whitespace, delimiter, getline

```
vector<string> Util::split(string str, char delimiter){
  vector<string> internal;
  stringstream ss(str); // Turn the string into a stream.
  string tok;

  while(getline(ss, tok, delimiter)) {
    internal.push_back(tok);
  }

return internal;
}
```

> string str = "k 1 1";
>
> getline(ss, tok, ' ')

if i try to check the size for the return vector it is size ONE.

> string str = "k,1,1";
>
> getline(ss, tok, ',')

However, if i change the delimiter to a comma and modify the string variable tok.

the size would then be THREE

So there is a problem with white spaces

What can i do to make this work? I've been on this for practically the whole day.

```
  int main(){

    Util src;
    int runProgram = 1;
    string input;

    while(runProgram!=0){
        cout << "Input your command to perfrom operation: " << endl;
        cin >> input; // user inputs "k 1 1"

       vector<string>sep=src.split(input, ' ');
       cout << sep.size() << endl; // size is one when it should be 3

    }
 }
```

Comment: The shown code will not work no matter what gets put into `tok`, since the `stringstream` gets constructed from some other, mysterious variable named `str`. Based on description, it looks to me like the shown code is not real code, but fantasy code. A real answer to a real question will require real code, not fantasy code.

Comment: You're right my mistake

Comment: Your code as shown now [works perfectly fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/062c49efb0278e67). Please provide an [mcve] that actually exhibits the problem.

Comment: I tried it and it's working with space delimiter. I used compiler clang C++11.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int delimiter(string & str,char ch){
    unsigned int count=1,size=str.size();
    if(size==0){
            return 0;
    }
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<size;i++){
            if(str[i]==ch){
                    count++;
            }
    }
    return count;
}

int main (int argc,char* array[]){
    string s="1 1 k";

    cout<<delimiter(s,' ') << endl;
}
```